# setup sub domain amazon using Route 53

Tags: amazon-web-services, dns, subdomain, amazon-route53

im really confused regarding setting up sub domain on amazon using their DNS service (hosted zones) and another 3rd party registrar. This is because i found different solutions some include add CNAME record and others say add using virtual host in the apache server

so should i do both or adding the CNAME in the records is enough.

so far, I have tried the first solution

I have added CNAME record (for example, let s assume my website is  example.com)
so I have added CNAME subdomain.example.com pointing to example.com/subdomain. I have waited for 1 day so the DNS settings to be propagated, still when I check the website i get an error.

i've also tried to add virtual host in my conf file, but it didn't work at all.

Comment: Follow this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17930972/how-can-i-use-aws-route-53-to-set-up-a-subdomain

Comment: hey @samben thank you for your answer, as i said i before i check other answers on stackoverflow, but they were not clear enough. for instance the guy mentioned he added CNAME pointing to mydomain.com. not to mydomain.com/api

Comment: @MarcelAlMutawa, I'm afraid it doesn't get much clearer than the answers to the question linked in the comments.  You set up a CNAME, which *cannot* include the path, and you configure your web server to expect that hostname as a virtual host.  The CNAME can reference any other valid hostname that resolves to the IP address of your server.  This question seems like a duplicate.

Comment: so you re saying I need both (CNAME+VIRTUAL HOST) to setup the subdomain ? I m confused because according to amazon documentation,"to setup sudomain you only need records sets" .another is it possible to add cname record (api.example.com) and point it to a path (example.com/api)??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the answer is very clear in the referenced link, but to clarify more what you should do , Follow the following steps:

**1** - Go to your AWS managment console -> Route 53.

According to your question, it looks that you are already using AWS DNS service, which means you have already created hosted zone (in case you don't have hosted zone create one )

For more info, follow the documentation http://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/creating-migrating.html

**2** - Click on the hosted zone, then click on create record set

the record set should be type **A** pointing to your @IP of your server (Elastic IP or Load balancer IP)

*Example:*

**subdomain.example.com -> Type A -> @IP**

By the way you can use **CNAME** record for **www.subdomain.example.com** that points to **subdomain.example.com**

**3** -  the last step is to add Virtual Host in your configuration file of your appache server.

open this file  **/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf.d**

Add the following Virtual Hosts

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerAdmin webmaster@yourdomain.com
DocumentRoot "/var/www/html/domain_folder"
ServerName example.com
ErrorLog "logs/example.com-error_log"
CustomLog "logs/example.com-access_log" common
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerAdmin webmaster@yourdomain.com
DocumentRoot "/var/www/html/subdomain_folder"
ServerName subdomain.example.com
ErrorLog "logs/subdomain.example.com-error_log"
CustomLog "logs/subdomain.example.com-access_log" common
</VirtualHost>
```

**4** - **Restart httpd** by typing this at the command line:

```
> sudo service httpd restart
```

PS : 
=> if this doesn't work, here is one possible cause. There might be another configuration file interfering with this one. Check for another .conf file in /etc/httpd/conf.d.  Often your primary httpd.conf will include another .conf file in this directory. Make sure it doesn’t have some Virtual Host settings which are interfering with yours.  If so, comment them out.

=> also make sure `NameVirtualHost *.80` is uncomment